# can not handle httpRequest parse Error in webFlux

Tags: spring-boot, web, spring-webflux

when httpStatus = 400(bad Request)，414(request URI too Long) and so on httpStatus error，can not monitor in webFlux。the spring version is 2.4.3。

for example ,the uri query has illegal character，return 400,but i can`t monitor in
AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler、WebFilter  or WebServerFactoryCustomizer
`localhost:8081/post/forward/test/form-url-encode?test=999&illegalChar=xxx}:,{;x.`

[image]

WebServerFactoryCustomizer can not monitor the response,this my code，but can not work。

```
public class ResponseNettyWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {


    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer ->
                httpServer.childObserve((conn, state) -> {
                    if (state == ConnectionObserver.State.CONNECTED) {
                        conn.channel().pipeline()
                                .addLast(GatewayNettyPipelineNameConstants.responseHttpStatusMonitorHandler, ResponseHttpStatusHandlerAdapter.INSTANCE);
                    }
                }));
    }
    

    @Slf4j
    static class ResponseHttpStatusHandlerAdapter extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
        static final ResponseHttpStatusHandlerAdapter INSTANCE = new ResponseHttpStatusHandlerAdapter();

        @Override
        public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
            try {
                if (msg instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) msg;
                    HttpResponseStatus httpResponseStatus = response.status();
                    if (!HttpResponseStatus.OK.equals(httpResponseStatus)) {
                        String httpStatus;
                        if (httpResponseStatus == null) {
                            httpStatus = "UNKNOWN_HTTP_STATUS";
                        } else {
                            httpStatus = String.valueOf(httpResponseStatus.code());
                        }
                        Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>(2);
                        tags.put("httpStatus", httpStatus);
                        //do send monitor 
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("NettyWebServeResponseStatusCustomizer.ResponseHttpStatusHandlerAdapter error!!! ");
            } finally {
                super.write(ctx, msg, promise);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSharable() {
            return true;
        }
    }


    private static String getPathFromUrlString(String originUri) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(originUri)) {
            return originUri;
        }
        int index = originUri.indexOf("?");
        if (index > 0) {
            return originUri.substring(0, index);
        }
        return originUri;
    }

    public static String getSubUriStringAfterCut(String fullOriginUri) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fullOriginUri)) {
            return fullOriginUri;
        }
        int putFullUriMaxLength = 60;
        if (fullOriginUri.length() > putFullUriMaxLength) {
            return fullOriginUri.substring(0, putFullUriMaxLength);
        }
        return fullOriginUri;
    }
}
```